# Which OTA offers PDF invoices with configurable addresses and bills for seating?

Tags: travel-agents

This is something that is definitely possible on the high street but I've struggled to find online.

I need to book a flight with British Airways and I need the airfare and seat reservation costs to be on the same invoice.

Every single OTA I've checked with requires me to pay for seat reservation in a separate transaction after the fact. BA itself doesn't seem to offer a proper invoice.

Comment: I’ve certainly never booked a flight with any airline without receiving something I would consider to be an invoice. If BA doesn’t offer “a proper invoice” it might be useful if you could edit your question to explain exactly what you mean by “a proper invoice”.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried booking directly on the BA website? You can add  seats while booking before you pay, so I assume that would end up on a single Invoice.